# Generate set of 2 elements tuples inside tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I have to generate tuple where inside this tuple will be tuples where the first element shows **i** number typed in string, and the second element shows string with example word + **i** in word.

I know that I can do it manually, but i want to do it in pythonic-way :)

```
PROPERTY_PRICES = (
        ('200', 'HUNDRED_2'),
        ('400', 'HUNDRED_4'),
        ('600', 'HUNDRED_6'),
        ...
        ('2000', 'HUNDRED_20'),
    )
```

My code but it only generates first elements '200', '400' etc. NOT second element. I cannot add another forloop after coma inside tuple():

```
PROPERTY_PRICES = (
        tuple( str(i) for i in range(200,2200,200) ),
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a comprehension inside `tuple`:

```
>>> property_prices =  tuple((str(i*100), f"HUNDRED_{i}") for i in range(2,22,2)),
>>> property_prices
((('200', 'HUNDRED_2'), ('400', 'HUNDRED_4'), ('600', 'HUNDRED_6'), ('800', 'HUNDRED_8'), ('1000', 'HUNDRED_10'), ('1200', 'HUNDRED_12'), ('1400', 'HUNDRED_14'), ('1600', 'HUNDRED_16'), ('1800', 'HUNDRED_18'), ('2000', 'HUNDRED_20')),)
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm :)

Comment: @RadosławHryniewicki you are welcome!, you may consider reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

```py
PROPERTY_PRICES = (
    str(i) for i in range(200,2200,200)
)

PROPERTY_NAMES = (
    f'HUNDRED_{i}' for i in range(2,22,2)
)

print(tuple(zip(PROPERTY_PRICES, PROPERTY_NAMES)))
```

Should give you:

```
>>> (('200', 'HUNDRED_2'), ('400', 'HUNDRED_4'), ('600', 'HUNDRED_6'), ('800', 'HUNDRED_8'), ('1000', 'HUNDRED_10'), ('1200', 'HUNDRED_12'), ('1400', 'HUNDRED_14'), ('1600', 'HUNDRED_16'), ('1800', 'HUNDRED_18'), ('2000', 'HUNDRED_20'))
```

Answer (score 0):

ı hope it work for u

```
  PROPERTY_PRICES = (
          str(i) for i in range(200,2200,200)
        )
    PROPERTY_VALUES =(
           "HUNDRED_"+str(i) for i in range(2,22,2)
       )
    list = tuple(zip(PROPERTY_PRICES,PROPERTY_VALUES))

    print(list)
```

Comment: Its pretty the same that @Shuvojit answered

Comment: ı was on pycharm and trying  when ı finished I posted it ı didnt see the @Shuvojit's answer :)  But we are thinking same :)